# Сколько можно провалить проверок внимательности за сутки без автобана?

Tags: поддержка, модерация

Как-то уже нарывался на автоматику, которая отстраняет от очереди проверок пользователей, которые отправляют тревоги, которые потом не распознаются как "полезные".

Потому с тех пор в очередях проверок принял за правило: если за сутки дважды не прошёл проверку -- то лучше отложить до следующего дня проверки. Во избежание.

Однако, не слишком ли жёсткий лимит я себе поставил? Есть ли какие-то официальные рекомендации, когда стоит чуть приостановиться и выждать денёк, чтобы не попасть под бездушную и неумолимую автоматику?

Или, если этот алгоритм не раскрывается во избежание манипуляций -- так намекнуть, чтобы всё же иметь какое-то представление.

PS Наверное, они на каждую очередь отдельно считаются, но мне такое в голове лень держать, просто считаю, что на третьем провале уже что-нибудь может заблокироваться. А уж до двух я хорошо считать умею, не собьюсь: 0, 1, 10 ;)

Comment: Полагаю, логичным было бы проверять соотношение успешных и проваленных проверок независимо от времени. Впрочем, понятия не имею, что там на самом деле.

Comment: Меня аудит больше всего бесит тем, что нужно лишнюю кнопку нажимать после поздравлений. Вот зачем это мне, если и так аудит пройден? Писали бы только когда не удалось пройти.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю пойти эмпирическим путём и завалить несколько проверок - может тогда удастся выяснить что-то более конкретное :-D

С другой стороны, а что это даст? Возможность безнаказанно зарабатывать знаки на очередях время от времени? Так участника, регулярно утверждающего левак или отклоняющего здравую правку, рано или поздно всё равно вычислят уже вполне конкретные люди, а не автоматика. И тогда перед ним встанут более интересные вопросы. Например, о значении числа 416.

Я кстати, пока не доходил ещё до такого состояния, чтобы запороть пару аудитов подряд. Если честно, я вообще не помню, чтобы я запарывал аудит. Может быть можно как-то в истории посмотреть, я не знаю.

Меня больше подбешивают поздравления о пройденном аудите, и необходимость нажимать кнопку "Далее" лишний раз. Кому это надо, если он пройден? Вот если запорол - то тут безусловно надо дать знать и предложить участнику подышать свежим воздухом или упасть в объятия Морфея перед дальнейшим разгребанием очередей.

Comment: `... о значении числа 416` — вы о  «прекращении обязательства невозможностью исполнения»? Ну так никто никаких договоров не заключал, деятельность сугубо добровольная. В придачу, тут не невозможность, а недобросовестность.

Comment: @Arhad [почти](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3776/176217)